# Join strings with different separators in Java

Tags: java, guava, joiner

I have a list of strings, e.g. days of the week. And I'd like to join them on comma, with "and" before the last element. E.g: "I'm available on Tue, Wed, Thu *and* Fri".

Something elegant like

```
Joiner.on(", ").join(days)
```

Does not work. Is there an elegant way to do it with Guava or similar library?

Thanks

Comment: Get the results from above statement, do split on last delimiter and append with whatever you want. I don't think there is any predefined method available for what you are looking for.

Comment: That's a great solution, but potentially incorrect if I don't use just dates. If I make it a generic function and the joined elements have the delimiter, I'm in trouble...

Comment: If you want generic function, then just don't append last element in your join condition (take that element out of the list you are passing to join) & write your own method to append the last one, which would be generic enough to handle any case. You can make this more generic by, creating a single method with index which separates first group of elements & second group of elements, and user defined join "text". Use two joins and append the results of two joins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java 6/7 compatible solution using Guava:

```
static String join(List<String> strings, String separator, String lastSeparator)
{
    checkNotNull(strings);
    switch (strings.size()) {
        case 0:
            return "";
        case 1:
            return strings.get(0);
        default:
            return Joiner.on(separator).join(strings.subList(0, strings.size() - 1))
                    + lastSeparator + strings.get(strings.size() - 1);
    }
}
```

or if you want to accept `Iterable` (and / or use more Guava stuff):

```
static String join(Iterable<String> strings, String separator, String lastSeparator)
{
    checkNotNull(strings);
    int size = Iterables.size(strings);
    switch (size) {
        case 0:
            return "";
        case 1:
            return strings.iterator().next();
        default:
            return Joiner.on(separator).join(Iterables.limit(strings, size - 1))
                    + lastSeparator + Iterables.getLast(strings);
    }
}
```

It handles all edge cases except null elements in `strings` - if you want to handle them and not throw NPE, add `.useForNull(stringForNull)` to your joiner.

Answer (score 4):

There is no straightforward solution, but you may consider mine:

```
final String COMMA = ", ", AND = " and ";
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri");
int last = list.size() - 1;

Joiner.on(AND).join(
    list.stream().limit(last).collect(joining(COMMA)),
    list.get(last)); // Tue, Wed, Thu and Fri
```

The another shorter way is:

```
list.stream().limit(last).collect(joining(COMMA, "", AND))
    .concat(list.get(last));
```

*These methods perfectly work for 2+ days.*

Edge cases (`list == null || list.isEmpty()` and `list.size() < 2`) may be handled by the `if` statements.

Comment: Thanks, it's ok, list or array, this is a direction I was thinking about...

Comment: P.S. The annoying thing is that I have to take care of edge cases. E.g. your code will throw exception on an empty list. It's not a lot of work, but I wish Guava had a one-line solution..

Answer (score 3):

Considering you're "not Java 8 friendly at this moment" (you probably mean lambdas and streams), how about using [`StringJoiner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringJoiner.html):

```java
public static String join(List<String> parts, String delimiter, String lastDelimiter) {
    StringJoiner joiner = new StringJoiner(delimiter, "", lastDelimiter);

    for (int i = 0; i < parts.size() - 1; i++) {
        joiner.add(parts.get(i));
    }

    return joiner.toString() + parts.get(parts.size() - 1);
}
```

However, doing the same with streams:

```java
public static String join(List<String> parts, String delimiter, String lastDelimiter) {
    return parts.stream()
            .limit(parts.size() - 1)
            .collect(Collectors.joining(delimiter, "", lastDelimiter))
            .concat(parts.get(parts.size() - 1));
}
```

**EDIT:** Just found [`String#join(CharSequence, Iterable<? extends CharSequence>)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#join-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.Iterable-):

```java
public static String join(List<String> parts, String delimiter, String lastDelimiter) {
    return String.join(delimiter, parts.subList(0, parts.size() - 1)) 
            + lastDelimiter + parts.get(parts.size() - 1);
}
```

In order to handle corner cases I'd go for [Xaerxess switch solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38608749/3429133).

Comment: Unfortunately, `StringJoiner` is also available only in Java 8+.

Comment: @Xaerxess: I know, that's why I said "you probably mean lambdas and streams". I thought (and still think) the OP was talking about the different syntax/coding style that comes with them. Of course, if he doesn't wants to (or can't) use JDK 8 at all, that's not a valid solution.

Answer (score 1):

Courtesy to Java having replaceFirst but no replaceLast, and assuming "_,_" will not appear in any of the elements/parts, I hacked the following function:

```
public static String join(Iterable<?> parts) {
    String reverse = new StringBuilder(Joiner.on("_,_").join(parts)).reverse().toString();
    reverse = reverse.replaceFirst("_,_", " dna ").replaceAll("_,_", " ,");
    return new StringBuilder(reverse).reverse().toString();
}
```

And then:

```
System.out.println(join(Arrays.asList("One", "Two", "Three", "Four")));
```

Gives:
    One, Two, Three and Four

Comment: You could use `replaceFirst("((?s:.*)_,_", "$1 and")`.